# link_to article.node.nodeName, topics_path(node) occur http://localhost:3000/topics.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my index.html.haml pages is:

```
.panel-heading
  %p.panel-title article
   .panel-body.row
     - @article.each do |article|
      %h5.col-md-6.clearfix
        = link_to article.title, article, style: "color: black";
          %span.badge.pull-right
            = article.comments.count
        .info.text-muted
         = link_to article.node.nodeName, topics_path(article.node.id)
         &bull;
         = article.comments.last.created_at
```

routes:

```
            articles GET    /articles(.:format)                               articles#index
                     POST   /articles(.:format)                               articles#create
         new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                           articles#new
        edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                      articles#edit
             article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#show
                     PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                     PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                     DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#destroy
              topics GET    /topics(.:format)                                 topics#index
               topic GET    /topics/:id(.:format)                             topics#show
               sites GET    /sites(.:format)                                  sites#index
                jobs GET    /jobs(.:format)                                   jobs#index
               notes GET    /notes(.:format)                                  notes#index
                     POST   /notes(.:format)                                  notes#create
            new_note GET    /notes/new(.:format)                              notes#new
           edit_note GET    /notes/:id/edit(.:format)                         notes#edit
                note GET    /notes/:id(.:format)                              notes#show
                     PATCH  /notes/:id(.:format)                              notes#update
                     PUT    /notes/:id(.:format)                              notes#update
                     DELETE /notes/:id(.:format)                              notes#destroy
                root GET    /                                                 articles#index
```

db `Article` and `Node` association have builded:

```
Article(id: integer, title: string, text: text, 
created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, user_id: integer, node_id:
integer,article_img_file_name: string, article_img_content_type:
string, article_img_file_size: integer, article_img_updated_at: datetime)

Node(id: integer, nodeName: string, created_at: datetime,
updated_at: datetime)
```

`the question is:`

i was click the `a` tag show this:

```
http://localhost:3000/topics.8
```

have tried

1. `= link_to article.node.nodeName, topics_path(article.node)`

   but don't make sense

   i thonght may `link_to` syntax wrong

what is the problem?
how can i solve it? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be `topic_path`
 instead of `topics_path`

```
= link_to article.node.nodeName, topic_path(article.node)
```

Check this route

```
topic GET /topics/:id(.:format) topics#show
```